# Which database is best suited for 100 Million time series data?

Tags: database, in-memory-database

I am looking for a database that gives me fast query and insert operations. Following are the possible expectations from the database.

1. A lightweight database.
2. Time series query database that can store approx 10K columns in a row and gives back all the columns on a time-based filter query (no aggregation function required).
3. Should have a retention policy (or some mechanism) for automatic data deletion.
4. Support concurrent query execution.
5. Should have Java and Python API (Connectors).

Any suggestions will be helpful.